# What should a PHP/MySQL web developer know about servers?

Tags: php, mysql

I develop websites using PHP and MySQL. What resources would a seasoned web developer recommend that would cover server-specific information relevant to the job of a developer.

If it helps, I work specifically with an Apache server (through my hosting company).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You say: **seasoned web developer** ... so:

So you should know as much as any respectable sys admin. This allows you to pick the right technologies for the business case/constraints.

You should also know about:

1. Database servers / DBA
2. Network architecture, bottleneck prevention, resource allocation
3. Network and system security
4. Protocols, firewalls, routing
5. Various application stack configurations (beyond LAMP or .NET)
6. Distributed systems, scalability
7. Technology evaluation (MoEs, MoPs and all that)

And tons of other stuff. Being a web developer is a specialization of 'developer' for a given *environment* ... as such you should know everything about that environment and everything that emerges out of, develops from or impacts on it.

Comment: +1 - especially a seasoned developer should make a normal admin ashamed with technical knowledge (not so much with procedures, like how to organize backups best). He should also know how to rate / plan servers for performance (especially database wise - IOPS etc.)

Comment: @Aiden Bell: Not sure what you're first line is aiming at. I am asking people who might call themselves "seasoned web developers" for advice. I am not labeling myself as one. Perhaps you misread?

Comment: @Aiden Bell: In response to the last portion of your answer, I am attempting to learn as much as possible about my environment, it's why I asked the question in the first place.

Comment: @Mike - I don't think you labeled yourself seasoned, I am stating what a seasoned web developer should know. Otherwise the first line would read "You say *you're a*: seasoned web developer"

Comment: @Mike I don't think Aiden was attacking you in any way, you may have misread his first statement.

Comment: @Aiden Bell: I apologize, I definitely misread your answer. Thank-you for responding, especially with what seems to be a very thorough answer!! Bottleneck prevention, application stack configurations, and technology evaluation are all new terms to me. Thanks!!

Comment: @Mike - No worries. Good luck with it, keep an open mind to things outside the web too. They sometimes end up there anyway (Erlang for one)

Answer (score 2):

Rule #1: Get your development environment as close as possible to the server environment. (I.e. use Apache on both, use the same versions of PHP and MySQL on both, ideally use the same operating system on both.)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the resources for the [Building Dynamic Websites](http://www.cs75.net/) course through the Harvard University Extension to be useful for learning/refreshing fundamental concepts, and also as a source for pointing me in the right direction when I need more specific information pertaining to the various technologies.

There are useful examples, cheatsheets, links to documentation, and, of course, audio/video lectures you can watch and/or listen to.